# Xamarin Native Facebook iOS does not use the Native FB app

Tags: facebook, xamarin, native

Im am trying to make my Xamarin iOS app use the native Facebook login but I get the browser instead of the native functionality.

I have: Url schemes, FacebookAppID, FacebookAppName in place in my info.plist

In my Facebook app I have added an iOS app and set the BundleId to my bundleId. Also I have set SingleSignon true (read that somewhere)
I have left the URL Scheme Suffix empty (don't know what to put there)

I have installed the FB app and logged in to this on the IPhone I am using but still the darn Webview is showing.

A login using the webview goes fine and if I quit the app and rerun the app the Xamarin Login button does say that I am logged in (displaying Logout)

Can anyone help?

Kind regards
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has intentionally disabled switching to the native App, see blog post from late 2015: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9

Answer (score 0):

try this, it supports native fb login https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinFormsNativeFacebook